# How can I access a web browser on the Nook Simple Touch?

Tags: epub, nook, ebook-readers, nook-simple-touch

I have a Nook Simple Touch and am frustrated by its lack of a web browser. I want to download ePub files from websites and read them on my Nook. I know there is supposed to be no web browser accessible, but I have heard that there are ways to get around that. What are they/is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this might help:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-secret-nook-simple-touch-web-browser.html
Relevant quote:

> With the NOOK Simple Touch with GlowLight and the original operating
>   system, the process is a bit more complex: Connect to a WiFi network,
>   use the Quick Nav Bar to go to Settings, and then choose Connect your
>   Facebook, Twitter, and Google Accounts.
>
> Tap on the link to Google; you will be asked to “Link your Google
>   Account,” but don’t bother. Instead, tap Forgot Password. Now look
>   closely and locate the small Home button that has mysteriously
>   appeared at the bottom of the page. Tap Home, and you will get to the
>   Google search engine, and from there you can connect to most Web
>   pages.

This page shows the same method with a video:
http://goodereader.com/blog/e-reader/how-to-access-the-hidden-internet-browser-on-the-nook-simple-touch-with-glowlight

Answer (score 3):

Unless you root your Nook, it has not been easy to access a web browser since firmware update 1.1.0 (November 7, 2011). It used to be easy prior to 1.1.0. There were some rumors earlier this year that NST would get a browser in a mid year firmware update but so far as I know, that never happened.

Note that 1.1.0 and future versions of the Nook have much improved fonts so if you were to downgrade your Nook to a version prior to 1.1.0, you would lose the better font rendering.

Barnes and Noble did not describe the firmware 1.1.0 changes in detail. So I did, here:

[Nook Simple Touch Firmware Update 1.1.0](http://www.filterjoe.com/2011/11/08/nook-simpletouch-firmware-update-1-10/)

As another post described, there's a fairly cumbersome method possible to access the browser, but the browser is not well supported by the Nook team.